# Mastermind Java Counting the "whites"

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out why sometimes my code for checking the whites in mastermind counts a value twice. I mean it counts the value both in white and in black. However, sometimes it works perfectly, the bug is not realized at every click and I can't find why.

Here's my method comparison() which compares my two arrays guess[] for the value the player enters and solution[] for the random values.

```
public void comparaison(){
    white = 0;
    black = 0;
    test = new boolean[columns]; 
    for(int x = 0 ; x < test.length ; x++){
        test[x] = false;
    }
    for (int i =0 ; i<columns; i++){
        System.out.println(solution[i]);
        if (solution[i] == guess[i]){
            test[i] = true;
            black++;
        }else{  
            for (int j=0;j < columns;j++){
                if(!test[j] && j!=i && guess[j] == solution[i]){
                    white++; 
                    test[j]=true;
                    break; 
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    System.out.println("black"+black);
    System.out.println("white"+white);
```

}

The 2 arrays are declared and initialized before and they are filled when the player click on a button representing a color (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qSjQ.png)). The test[] array is declared before too.

Comment: you don't need to set every element of a boolean array to false. It's already is set to false when you initialize a boolean array.

Comment: Cannot see any image

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs if you have a misplaced color before a well placed color, such as this :

```
           1 2 3 4
Solution : A A B B
Guess    : B B B B
```

- 1: B matches white with 3
- 2: B matches white with 4
- 3: B matches black with 3 again
- 4: B matches black with 4 again

You may have to check for the blacks before doing another pass for the whites.

**Edit**: *the new code should look like this:*

```
for (int i=0 ; i<columns ; i++) {
    if (solution[i] == guess[i]) {
        test[i] = true;
        black++;
    }
}

for (int i=0 ; i<columns ; i++) {
    if (solution[i] != guess[i]) {
        for (int j=0 ; j<columns ; j++) {
            if(!test[j] && j!=i && guess[j] == solution[i]) {
                test[j] = true;
                white++; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know understand the problem. But actually I think I'm already checking the blacks before the whites in the first loop, aren't I? What would you suggest? A new loop?

Comment: Two loops yes. A first one for only the blacks, then one for the remaining whites.

Comment: That's why I'm already doing I think. Would you please write the code?